# Filter the particular dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

```
d = {'id': 'ccccc',
     'school': [{'s_id': '12', 'city': 'xxx'}, {'s_id': '11', 'city':'yy'}]}
```

I want to filter it using s_id. Suppose if some one want to filter the `s_id = 11` it should return `{'s_id': '11', 'city':'yy'}.` Please answer using the filter keyword.

Comment: *please answer it using filter keyword.* is this a homework? what have you tried?

Comment: Please read 5.1.3 http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Please follow [general](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) question [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s_id=11
>>> [i for i in d['school'] if i['s_id'] == str(s_id)]
[{'s_id': '11', 'city': 'yy'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use python built-in filter function :

```
>>> filter(lambda d:d['s_id']=='11',d['school'])
[{'s_id': '11', 'city': 'yy'}]
```

as a bonus, if you want to sort by 's_id'
you can do:

```
>>> for school in sorted(d['school'],key=lambda d:d['s_id']):
...     print school
... 
{'s_id': '11', 'city': 'yy'}
{'s_id': '12', 'city': 'xxx'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is is using `filter` and partial functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from functools import partial

d = {'id': 'ccccc','school': [{'s_id': '12', 'city': 'xxx'}, {'s_id': '11',
'city':'yy'}]}

def myfilter(school, s_id):
    return school['s_id'] == str(s_id)

f = partial(myfilter, s_id = 11)
print filter(f, d['school'])
```